# Trying to get an attribute with Excel using XPathOnUrl, but the result is blank

Tags: excel, xpath

I succeeded with this to get "The Name": `=Dump(XPathOnUrl(B3;"//a/div"))`
And to get "The address": `=Dump(XPathOnUrl(B3;"//a/p"))`

But I don not know how to retrieve the `href` attribute of the `a` element.

I already used this `=XPathOnUrl(B3;"//a/@href")`, but the result is blank.

Here's the HTML:

```
    <div class="showroomlist clearfix">
        <ul class="clearfix card-wrap">
                            <li class="card">
                    <a class="center" href="https://www.somelink.com/thelink-1762" title="The Title">
                        <div class="showroomname">The Name </div>
                        <p>The address</p>
                    </a>
                    <div class="center">
                        <span onclick="gd.url.goto('https://www.somelink.com/thelink-1762')"
                           class="button-secondary"
                           title="Contact us">
                            Contact us </span>
                    </div>
                </li>
```

Really appreciate for some one who can help me ..

Answer (score 0):

A specific XPath-1.0 expression to get the `href` attribute could be

```
//li[@class='card']/a[@class='center']/@href
```

Result is

> https://www.somelink.com/thelink-1762

---

Similar to what you already mentioned in your question, the other expressions would be

1. `//li[@class='card']/a[@class='center']/div` for "The Name"
2. `//li[@class='card']/a[@class='center']/p` for "The address"

I tested all of these. If they don't work, your XPath processor probably doesn't support attributes.

Comment: Halo zx485 thanks for the answer...

too bad in my end, it not show the url .. what tools you use to show that ?  thanks

Comment: I used a Linux XSLT processor to evaluate the XPath. But what tool _do you use_? You didn't mention it in your question.

Comment: im not use any tools, only excel xpath tools using command like this : =Dump(XPathOnUrl(B3;"//a/p")) to fetch the address

Comment: So you're using Excel. That's good to know. I changed your question title to attract proper audience.